# Апелляция на отклонённую тревогу

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Я уважаю работу всех модераторов (или других проверенных участников сообщества), но в данном случае я думаю, что ко мне и моей тревоге отнеслись несправедливо.

Вот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1389216/%d0%90%d0%b1%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83), который я считаю бесполезным, так как маловероятно, что люди будут искать решение проблемы в такой узкой формулировке (обсуждения на Мете [№1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89996/1144358) и [№2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79345/1144358), [3-я или 4-я причина в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0.)), и его "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством".

Его бессмысленность неоспорима, но мне также не понравилась формулировка отказа в принятии моей тревоги:

> тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства

В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) написано, что это обоснование отказа - не единственная причина, по которой [просят](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts#:%7E:text=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C-,%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0,-%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9) отметить сообщение тревогой. Либо это чей-то настроенный шаблонный ответ, либо меня приняли за неопытного составителя тревог.

### Приложение

| [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] |
| --- | --- |
| Рис. 1. Бесполезный вопрос | Рис. 2. Причина отклонённой тревоги |

## UPD

Рассмотрим прочие предлоги для закрытия вопроса (в комментариях было предложено отметить пункт "необходимо улучшить").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Этот вопрос дубликат? Возможно, но найти его оригинал, имеющий соответствующе узкую формулировку, весьма затруднительно.
2. Специфичная для сообщества проблема?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Нет, так как проблема не в опечатке, она воспроизводится; включает желаемое поведение, текущее поведение и минимальный код; вопрос написан на русском языке; даже если это учебное задание, код приведён; [вопрос по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:%7E:text=%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%3A%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%2C%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%3B).

3,4,5. Нет, нет и нет. Суть вопроса понятна, он включает одну очень узкую проблему, а объективный ответ дан и принят.

Таким образом, за неимением более подходящего предлога необходимо было пометить вопрос как вопрос очень низкого качества.

## UPD 2

Спасибо за конструктивное обсуждение, но моя апелляция осталась безответной. В рамках текущего вопроса я хочу узнать, **почему вопрос закрыли как вопрос не по теме, отклонив при этом мою тревогу**? Предпосылок к закрытию вопроса по названной причине нет, так как в он соответствует критериям, описанным в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134765/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too Localized, на который вы ссылаетесь, это вопрос, на который **невозможно дать ответ** из-за чрезвычайно малого количества потенциальных отвечающих.

> "Too localized" should be used for **very tiny geographic regions** or
> **vanishingly small periods of time**. It is used when a question cannot
> possibly be answered because nobody participating in the site is
> likely to know the answer, and even if it were answered, nobody else
> would care.

Что легко опровергается просто взглядом на вопрос - он не привязан географически, он не привязан к короткому периоду времени, и на него дано два ответа.

Это была причина для закрытия вопросов вида:

> На чем в Питере модно писать фронт?

Или

> Актуален ли jQuery в январе 2022?

Не говоря уже про то, что эту причину давно удалили, а на ru-SO ее вообще никогда не было. В вашем же толковании эту причину можно легко натянуть на практически любой вопрос, включая все заданные вами на сайте.

Представьте, что вы получили бы от текущих участников комментарий "бессмысленность ваших вопросов и ответов неоспорима" - остались бы вы на сайте? Если нет - то почему вы позволяете себе настолько высокомерно относится к вопросам от новичков? Если так делать - вопросов вообще не останется.

То, что 10 лет назад на enSO была причина закрытия с неудачной формулировкой - не повод сейчас устраивать массовые чистки вопросов на ruSO, придумывая обоснования на ходу.

Это обычный онтопичный вопрос, не домашка, с кодом, закрыт он только потому, что иногда нормальные вопросы закрываются из-за зашкаливающего вахтерства, и из-за того, что пару участников не заметили "явного описания проблемы" в виде комментария в коде.

А ваша тревога отклонена, потому что кто-то из модераторов в очереди нажал "отклонить" (и правильно сделал) - закрытие вопросов должно проходить через очередь и голосование, а не прямой тревогой модератору.

Comment: Поверхностно обежав взглядом ваше сообщение, хочу отметить, что обозначенный вопрос закрыт, несмотря на ваши убеждения (`кто-то в очереди нажал "оставить открытым" (и правильно сделал)`), причём закрыт несправедливо (даже для вас это `обычный онтопичный вопрос`), я руководствуюсь текущими версиями справки, которая указывает на вопрос английской Мете с таким [ответом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89992/1144358), содержащим выдержки из подкаста. Что касается меня - мои вопросы содержали куда более подробное описание моего положения

Comment: Я принимаю вашу критику о моём нетолерантном выражении о вопросах низкого качества и хочу принести свои извинения, если это доставило вам много неудовольствия, но маловероятно, что автор вопроса увидит моё сообщение. Хочу также уточнить, что мне делать, если голосование для меня недоступно

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов руководствуйтесь чем угодно :) Вопрос на английской мете, на который вы ссылаетесь, закрыт с указанием на более новое решение. Если коротко - ваша ссылка имеет только историческое значение, не более.

Comment: «Это обычный онтопичный вопрос» — поэтому ruSO в дерьме ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов вот только закрывать онтопичные вопросы по надуманным неактуальным уже лет 8 причинам - это нарушение правил. такие дела.

Comment: @andreymal https://en.meming.world/wiki/Always_has_been

Comment: Извините, но вы меня ограничиваете в моих "конституционных [справочных] правах": `закрытие вопросов должно проходить через очередь и голосование, а не прямой тревогой модератору` - но согласно [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) я должен отмечать сообщение, `из-за которого мне некомфортно или я считаю, что оно неуместно`

Comment: @andreymal вы как будто первый день на SO. начнете фильтровать простые или криво оформленные вопросы - новичкам не на что будет отвечать. и сообществу кирдык. хотя, в принципе, так и вышло - вахтеры победили

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов "неуместно" - это мат и спам. а возможный офтопик - это "возможно стоит закрыть", а не "СРОЧНО! МОДЕРАТОРЫ! НЕУМЕСТНЫЙ КОНТЕНТ!"

Comment: Но я же не могу, отмечая вопрос подходящей тревогой, указать, что этот вопрос следует рассмотреть к закрытию голосованием. Или могу? А что насчёт тревог из раздела "необходимо улучшить" - к ним не такое резкое отношение у модерирующих участников (такие тревоги не звучат образом, подобным этому: `"СРОЧНО! МОДЕРАТОРЫ! НЕУМЕСТНЫЙ КОНТЕНТ!"`)? P.S. `надуманным неактуальным уже лет 8 причинам` - причина актуальна, так как указана в справке, а если один вопрос на Мете должен был полностью заменить другой, то заменили бы ссылку в справке на ссылку на новый вопрос, а не помечали бы старый

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов ну ок, вы нашли в справке очевидно неакутальную ссылку, ведущую на вопрос, у которого прямо в шапке написано "больше неактуально". может быть стоит на мете предложить справку обновить, а не начинать закрывать все подряд с обоснованием "там же ссылка, и все равно что по ней написано"? Может быть от этого больше будет пользы, чем от закрытий по правилам 8-летней давности? По поводу тревоги - этот тип тревоги падает напрямую модераторам (которых мало), а не в очередь закрытия. Тревогу завернули модераторы (т.к. тип тревоги явно не тот), вопрос закрыли обычные участники в очереди.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов - заменили бы ссылку в справке на ссылку на новый вопрос - я, как бывший модератор, могу вас уверить, что за справкой никто не следит, и ссылки там ведут куда угодно :)   Эта ссылка была просто скопипащена с английской справки в момент настройки сайта, и с тех пор там висит. Нет за ней никакой хитрой задумки, нет никакого процесса обновления ссылок на актуальные, это просто артефакт копипасты, и все.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов более-менее можно полагаться на ссылки на русскую мету. все, что ведет из справки на meta.stackexchange.com с 99% вероятностью давно неактуально.

Comment: Я понял, что на справку в местах сомнительных (таких, как тот вопрос) лучше не полагаться. Для прочих подобных сообщений я буду использовать тревоги из раздела "необходимо улучшить". Я приму ваш ответ с учётом всех комментариев, так как он отвечает на мои вопросы, кроме одного: у меня кто-нибудь заберёт отклонённую тревогу, ведь вопрос всё равно оказался закрытым?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов отклонение тревоги нельзя провернуть назад, по крайней мере в мод тулзах, будет висеть 1 в статистике.